# Automating copy of Google Cloud Compute instances between projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, ansible, google-compute-engine, terraform

I need to move more than 50 compute instances from a Google Cloud project to another one, and I was wondering if there's some tool that can take care of this.

Ideally, the needed steps could be the following (I'm omitting regions and zones for the sake of simplicity):

- Get all `instances` in `source project`
- For each `instance` get `machine sizing` and the list of attached `disks`

  - For each `disk` create a `disk-image`
  - Create a `new instance`, of type `machine sizing`, in `target project` using the first `disk-image` as source
  - Attach remaining `disk-image`s to `new instance` (in the same order they were created)

I've been checking on both Terraform and Ansible, but I have the feeling that none of them supports creating disk images, meaning that I could only use them for the last 2 steps.

I'd like to avoid writing a shell script because it doesn't seem a robust option, but I can't find tools that can help me doing the whole process either.

Just as a side note, I'm doing this because I need to change the subnet for all my machines, and it seems like you can't do it on already created machines but you need to clone them to change the network.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool by GCP to migrate the instances from one project to another one.

I was able to find, however, an [Ansible module to create Images](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_compute_image_module.html).

In Ansible:
You can specify the “source_disk” when creating a “gcp_compute_image” as [mentioned here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_compute_image_module.html#examples)

Frederic